# RoboSpice or Retrofit or Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, robospice

After going through the ways of calling web service calls in android.It's not recommended to use `AsyncTask` because of issues like device configuration change.

And `Loaders` are mainly used for interacting with database and `Services` mostly for long running operations.

Many answers says, to use libraries like `Volley` or `Robospice` or `Retrofit`.

What would be the most efficient one among them?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: why close? I don't understand.

Comment: I think this question is subjective thats why they have downvoted you. Its best to complete some research yourself first before asking questions on SO. I use robospice a lot for my work and think it is fantastic - only problem with it is that it has not been updated for a while making me think that the library is not maintained well.

Comment: oh okay, i have used asynctask and loaders, and after doing some research, i found robospice and retrofit are being used a lot.But retrofit doesn't take care of device configuration change i guess, there must be way to take care of that, but it does convert json repsonse to pojo class and use the spring concept. Now, i think of using robospice as it does caching and handles device configuration issue. Thankx for the reply @Simon

Comment: Yes - that is another benefit of using robospice but just keep in mind that robospice does not handle caching of lists of objects. It will only cache the object if your api returns one single object which is rare in today's technology architecture for rest. You can make robospice cache lists of objects but it is not built out of the box and you might have spend some time discovering how to do it. If retrofit can cache lists of objects out of the box, I would go for that.

Comment: Thankx for this information @Simon . I thought it will cache all objects returned from the server.  i will surely do some more research on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across different approaches in the past years and applied some of them in the real apps and some of them in some simple proof of concepts.

Here's my opinion:

The best option for communication with web services in Android is `Retrofit` **+** `RxJava`

`Retrofit` is compatible with `RxJava`. With such approach, you have clean and simple interface, you are able to **handle errors** and **manipulate HTTP responses** as `Observable` streams thanks to `RxJava`. Such approach is becoming good practice and standard for Android applications right now.